# Error creating ingress path with GCE + ExternalName

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an `ExternalName` service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalName: my-site.com
  ports:
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  type: ExternalName
```

And an Ingress path:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: external
          servicePort: 443
        path: /*
```

But saving the ingress returns:

> Error during sync: error while evaluating the ingress spec: service "default/external" is type "ExternalName", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"

GCE ingress *should* support `ExternalName` services (or at least there isn't easily findable documentation suggesting otherwise) and that error is hard to track down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCE ingresses do not support type: ExternalName due to the fact that they use GCE LB as the providing infrastructure. the GCE LB can't use it as a backend.

I recommend posting this as a Feature Request on [Google's Issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: was an issue ever logged about this?

Comment: Now, this setup seems to be possible (no "ExternalName" error). However, I am facing a different issue - GKE Ingress uses healthchecks for backends which don't seem to work with ExternalName services, even though the service is configured properly and gives 200 code when testing manually.

Comment: tbh I'd have to look under the hood for that, my guess is that because the externalName is performing a redirect, the first response you get from the server is not 200 but something else. The end result is a 200. If you were to curl the same IP:port that the healthcheck is using, you likely don't get a 200

Comment: ExternalName works for you? I'm having trouble getting it to work. If you wouldn't mind, could you take a look at my setup is here? Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945853/connecting-external-service-to-gcp-gke-kubernetes-cluster-with-googles-external .