# Connecting External Service to GCP GKE Kubernetes Cluster with Google's External HTTP(S) Load Balancer

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to connect an external webflow page to our kubernetes cluster ingress on GCP GKE. Specifically, I want everything at [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to go to the external webflow service, and everything at [www.domain.com/app](http://www.domain.com/app) to go to our local service in the cluster.

I've seen this question [Ingress Nginx Proxy to Outside Website (Webflow hosted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919773/ingress-nginx-proxy-to-outside-website-webflow-hosted) and followed it, but I couldn't get it working. I keep getting an error
`Translation failed: invalid ingress spec: service "default/external-service" is type "ExternalName", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"; service "default/external-service" is type "ExternalName", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"`

Here's my setup

External Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalName: participant-homepage-9f8712.webflow.io
  ports:
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ExternalName
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: _,
    ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: _,
    ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: _,
    ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule: _,
    ingress.kubernetes.io/https-target-proxy: _,
    ingress.kubernetes.io/preserve-host: "false"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-cert: _,
    ingress.kubernetes.io/static-ip: _,
    ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: _,
    ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: _,
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: _,
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      proxy_ssl_name participant-homepage-9f8712.webflow.io;
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: participant-homepage-9f8712.webflow.io
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: external-service
    servicePort: 443
  rules:
  - host: www.honeybeehub.xyz
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: external-service
          servicePort: 443
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: _._._._
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the steps on the question you quoted [Ingress Nginx Proxy to Outside Website (Webflow hosted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919773/ingress-nginx-proxy-to-outside-website-webflow-hosted) are not working, is because that question focuses on EKS (Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service). ExternalName Services are not supported in GCE Ingress, as you can see in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53107348/error-creating-ingress-path-with-gce-externalname).
What I can recommend to you is to post it as a Feature Request on the [Google's Issue tracker](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers&sa=D&source=docs&ust=1636750079733000&usg=AOvVaw2ocSL1lAPc3gUomJhKCRJm)